# How to add a continuous number to HTML tag attribute value inside The Loop

Tags: loop

I am looking to get a result like this in my list of posts:

```
<div data-panel="panel-1">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
<div data-panel="panel-2">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
<div data-panel="panel-3">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
<div data-panel="panel-4">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

At this moment I have the following:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div data-panel="panel-1">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

So all I need is panel number to go up on each post?

Comment: This has nothing to do with WordPress but very, very basic PHP and will likely get closed. You need an incrementer: `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $i = 1; ?>

        <div data-panel="panel-<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>`

Comment: Thanks but it repeated "panel-1" over and over?

Comment: Take `$i = 1;` out of the loop, move it before the `while`

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) property [`$current_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties)

> **$current_post**
>      (available during [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)) index of the post currently being displayed.

It can be used for your purpose.